# How to reconcile active and passive observation in quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedingers-cat

The two-slit experiment is a classic example of how measurements can affect the behavior of particles. This seems reasonable because, to my knowledge, the measurement is "active" in that it adds energy to the system. But how is this reconciled with macroscopic observations (such as looking at Schroedinger's cat) that are "passive" in that they are collecting information already there without affecting the system?

Comment: We don't know if the cat is alive or dead until we open the box & observe it, so we are actually affecting the system (it's in the "superposition" of alive+dead until we collapse it)

Comment: @KyleKanos This is a rather out-dated interpretation. The observation does not collapse the state according to decoherence theory, the interaction with the environment does.

Comment: Schroedinger's cat is a very poorly formulated paradox. The most obvious problems are that a cat can not live in a completely closed box to begin with and a nuclear decay doesn't even happen in a completely closed box. Once we allow for the box to be open enough to allow for either, the setup simply represents the same kind of weak measurement that causes the gradual shift from quantum phenomena to classical ones that can, for instance, be identified with the particle states that cause tracks in particle detectors. Schroedinger hasn't taught as anything about QM except how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well Schrödinger's cat is considered to be *not* "passive", otherwise the paradox is moot.

The best explanation we know is [decoherence theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoherence). That is we disregard environmental micro-states that are macroscopically the same, in this interpretation one gets the density matrix $\rho = \frac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for the states "cat alive" and "cat dead" without any observation. That is classical probability is created from quantum probability by decoherence.

The bottom line is, that the cat is coupled strongly to the environment at all times, while the particle in the double slit experiment is not (unless we measure it, which requires some strong interaction).

Comment: A good way of looking at this is by replacing the cat with the decay products of the nuclear decay. In an infinite potential well the nucleus and its decay products will exist in a mixed state at almost all times after the preparation. Since the phase space of the decay products, especially that of gammas, is so much larger than that of the nucleus, opening the potential well even a little to make the measurement will let the gammas escape and the state will immediately "collapse" as a consequence of the measurement. Any thermodynamic coupling to the environment will do the same.